# How to use octicons in Elm or how to parse svg from string?

Tags: svg, elm, octicons

So I'd like to use githubs [octicons](https://github.com/primer/octicons#install) in Elm as svg nodes. Although I'm not sure that this is a good idea but I figured here is one way I could do it:

I could do pass the svg tags as string with flags to an Elm app calling:

```
   const octicons = require('octicons');
   const plusIcon = octicons.plus.toSVG();
```

And then just put that as a flag. But then how can I parse that string as an svg node?

I couldn't find any way to do that.

Although I don't really need to have it as an svg node. I just need the tag in my view to use that icon. So any solution to show those octicon icons would suffice. I just thought it would neat to have those as svg nodes in Elm.

In any case, maybe there is a better/easier way to use octicons in Elm?

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of returning an svg string you could return an object with all necessary attributes. In opticons you have [`options`](https://github.com/primer/octicons#octiconsissueoptions) and [`path`](https://github.com/primer/octicons#octiconspersonpath). In case of path you can either parse the tag yourself or get something like [`jQuery.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) do it for you. After that from inside elm [`elm-lang/svg`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/svg/2.0.0/Svg) has all the utility: [`Svg.svg`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/svg/2.0.0/Svg#svg) with [`Svg.path`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/svg/2.0.0/Svg#path) inside.